# Xpages and JAXBContext: NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils

Tags: xml, jaxb, xpages

I'm trying to work with XML via JAXBContext in IBM Domino XPages app in order to convert object to XML string.
Method is following (ContactPhoneNumber.toXML()):

```
public String toXml() throws Exception {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("net.portal.model", ContactPhoneNumber.class.getClassLoader());
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, sw);
    return sw.toString();
}
```

I'm getting Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: om.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils (initialization failure)
```

Any suggestions, how to fix it?
Thank you in advance for support!

Edited:
Domino r9.0.1 FP2 x64 + ExtLib installed separetly via updateSite. I did not import any JARs for XML, use only existing packages in Designer / Domino:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
```

Or I should import external JARs??

Stacktrace here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57070052/IBM/Xpages_and_JAXBContext_NoClassDefFoundError_com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils_StackTrace

Class source-code here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57070052/IBM/ContactPhoneNumber.java

Comment: Please, ask me additional questions in case you need additional info on my issue! Thank you!

Comment: Which release? How were the JARs imported into the project? 8.5.x differs from 9.0.x regarding the build path.

Comment: Also has this worked in previous versions? Note, 9.0 is stricter in terms of what's allowed to be done by code within the NSF. If packaging in an OSGi plugin is not an option, you might be best advised looking for an IBM package for XML output, possibly something in the source code of Extension Library.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your questions, I did update the topic. Interesting, that I do not see class "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils" in designer. Actually, the exception is exactly telling me this... )

Comment: Ok, after importing JARs from here: https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.11/ I'm getting security exception... So, the question: is there any possibility to use internal XML functionality shipped with Domino, without need to change java.policy, OR the only way to import external JARs?

Comment: Guys, in case you have any suggestions for me - they are welcome, meanwhile I will manually parse/build XML using javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory; and javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser; - they evailable in Domino.

Comment: If you get a security exception, you could consider modifying the `java.policy` file on server to grant the required rights.

Comment: Hi Lauri, yes, it's clear. The idea was to use only standard functionality of Domino without importing external JARS and changing java.policy.